# uwsgi mountpoints issue: RuntimeError: class.__dict__ not accessible in restricted mode

Tags: python, nginx, pyramid, uwsgi

Pyramid application throws `RuntimeError: class.__dict__ not accessible in restricted mode` into `python2.7/site-packages/zope/interface/declarations.py` while gets request from nginx by uwsgi. In this case uses uwsgi mount point configuration. Without mount point - no errors.

Have following configuration based on nginx + uwsgi + pyramid + supervisor:

Pyramid configuration ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = PATH_TO_SOCK
virtualenv = PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV
module = MODULE_NAME
mount = /URL_SUB_PATH=MODULE_NAME/uwsgiapp.py
manage-script-name = true
env = PASTE_CONFIG=%p
```

uwsgi.py:

```
from paste.deploy import loadapp
app = loadapp('config:' + os.environ['PASTE_CONFIG'])    

def application(environ, start_response):
    if os.environ.get('WSGI_FILE_WRAPPER', 'yes').lower() in ('no', 'false'):
        environ.pop('wsgi.file_wrapper', None)
    return app(environ, start_response)
```

command for run from supervisor.conf:

```
command=PATH_TO_VIRTUALENV/bin/uwsgi --ini-paste PATH_TO_PYRAMID_CONF_INI
```

and fragment of nginx config:

```
upstream UPSTREAM_NAME {
        server unix:///PATH_TO_SOCK;
}

location /URL_SUB_PATH/ {
        uwsgi_pass UPSTREAM_NAME;
        include     uwsgi_params;
}
```

What is the reason for this unexpected behavior?

Comment: do not call a wsgi module uwsgi.py. It will class with the embedded 'uwsgi' module